# Choose employee name and his/her ID will show in the textbox in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I want to show the ID of Francis when I click it. Also in the database there is a list of employee name and ID. So if I click Francis or Ivann. In the textbox (the arrow) it will show his/her ID specified only in the employee name. :)
[image]

Also here's is my code.

```
<!--Create-->
<?php
  include "config.php";
  include "header.php";
?>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['bts'])):
    if($_POST['id']!=null && $_POST['en']!=null && $_POST['date']!=null && $_POST['dp']!=null && $_POST['deduc']!=null){
       $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO personal(id_personal,name,date,datepaid,deduction) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
       $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $id, $en, $date, $dp, $deduc);

       $id = $_POST['id'];
       $en = $_POST['en'];
       $date = $_POST['date'];
       $dp = $_POST['dp'];
       $deduc = $_POST['deduc'];

       if($stmt->execute()):
?>
<p></p>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
  <strong>Alright!</strong> Successfully added.
</div>
<?php
  endif;
  } else {
?>
<p></p>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
  <strong>Error!</strong> You must fill all the blanks.
</div>
<?php
}
  endif;
?>
  <p>
</p>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
  <form role="form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="id">Employee ID</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" placeholder="Enter ID"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="en">Employee Names</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="en" name="en">
        <option>Choose</option>
        <?php
          include("alqdb.php");
          $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT EmpFName FROM employee");
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<option>".$row["EmpFName"]."</option>";
          }
        ?>
        </select>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Date</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" id="date"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dp">Date to be Paid</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dp" id="dp"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sal">Salary</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sal" id="sal" placeholder="Salary"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="amnt">Amount</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amnt" id="amnt" placeholder="Enter Amount"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="deduc">Deduction</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deduc" id="deduc" value="0.00" readonly/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="bts" class="btn btn-default">Ok</button>
  </form>
<?php
  include "footer.php";
?>
<!--Table-->
<?php
  include "config.php";
  include "header.php";
?>
  <p>
</p>
<label>List of Transactions</label>
<table id="ghatable" class="display table table-bordered table-stripe" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Date to be Paid</th>
      <th>Deduction</th>
      <th>Action</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM personal");
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()):
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['id_personal'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo date("F j, Y", strtotime($row['date'])) ?></td>
      <td><?php echo date("F j, Y", strtotime($row['datepaid'])) ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['deduction'] ?></td>
      <td>
        <a href="update.php?u=<?php echo $row['id_personal'] ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit</a>
        <a onclick="return confirm('Are you want deleting data')" href="delete.php?d=<?php echo $row['id_personal'] ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <?php
    endwhile;
  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php
  include "footer.php";
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    $("#amnt, #sal").keyup(function() {
        $("#deduc").val(($("#sal").val() - $("#amnt").val()).toFixed(2));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply build that kind of Functionality directly in the Options of your Employee Select Box (By the Way, you had 2 closing Select tags in your code). Anyways, to do this you could leverage the HTML5 `data` Attribute as shown below:

```
    <select class="form-control" id="en" name="en">
        <option>Choose</option>
        <?php
            include("alqdb.php");

            // ALSO ADD THE ID COLUMN TO YOUR SELECT QUERY SO YOU HAVE IT AVAILABLE TO YOU.
            $result =   mysqli_query($con, "SELECT EmpFName, id FROM employee");

            while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                // YOUR OPTION SHOULD HAVE A VALUE ATTRIBUTE IF YOU WISH TO SAVE THE FORM.
                // CHANGE $row["id"] TO THE APPROPRIATE NAME OF THE FIELD
                // CORRESPONDING TO EMPLOYEE ID.
                echo "<option value='{$row["EmpFName"]}' data-emp-id='{$row["id"]}'>";
                echo $row["EmpFName"] . "</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Then in Javascript (JQuery used here):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var empName = $("#en");
                var empID   = $("#id");

                empName.on("change", function(evt){
                    var eN  = $(this);          
                    var eID = eN.children('option:selected').attr("data-emp-id");
                    empID.val(eID);
                });

                $("#amnt, #sal").keyup(function() {
                    $("#deduc").val(($("#sal").val() - $("#amnt").val()).toFixed(2));
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: when I choose a name, an employee ID specified only in that employee name will display in that textbox.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but still it not working. :'( there is no value in the textbox when I choose an employee name. :(

Comment: @FrancisVargas     You just have to make sure you **Change `$row['id']` to the appropriate value and also use the entire "<select>...</select> posted above with the `data-emp-id`**. That should work....

Comment: I think the problem is that $row['id']. I don't see any $row['id']. also how can I change it? :)

Comment: What is **the name of the Field (in your DB Table) that holds the Employee ID**? If you get this name, just substitute it for `$row['field_name_for_employee_id_in_your_table']` And most importantly; you should make that field available through your Query: `
          $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT EmpFName, id FROM employee");` ***Notice that we now included a new field to the Select clause: `id`***

Comment: @FrancisVargas    The code is now again updated.  You may **refer to the newly added comment** above the Query... Cheers and Good Luck...

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR HELP! CHEERS! IT WORKED! HAHA. :)

Comment: hello @Poiz?! how about showing it to a drop down. when I choose Francis, inside of that drop down will have a value that only specified the name of Francis? all value that only specified Francis?

Comment: @FrancisVargas    Do you want the **ID** Field now to be a Select Box as well?

Comment: yes! :) but the content is an event, it only contains an event only the name of Francis/other name? I hope you can help me with that. :)

Comment: I must send you a code and picture. but I think I just pm you. but how? :)

Comment: sorry but I don't have Skype. :( how about twitter or facebook?
twitter: FJVargas22
facebook: Astig Vargas

Comment: sorry. haha. :) it's Francis Vargas. the pic is an anime.

Comment: check your e-mail. I already send it. thank you again by the way. haha. :)

Comment: @FrancisVargas     Does your table have an ID Field because what you want to achieve can better be done via AJAX....

Comment: I think I don't have an ID field. it's also ok if you use AJAX. :)

Comment: hello @Poiz? can you help me? :(

Comment: @FrancisVargas    What is your Problem, again?

Comment: sorry late reply. this time it is about filter. :( if it is ok, can we discuss it on facebook? :)

Comment: also, did you unfriend me in facebook? :( @Poiz

Comment: @FrancisVargas     now, why should i do that?

Comment: what do mean? about the unfriend? because I don't see your name in fb. :( did you change your name? what's your name again in fb? :) @Poiz